# filling a drop downbox using ng-options instead of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angularJS and i have been trying to fill a dropdown list box for about a week now. i can not get it to populate to save my life. am i setting this up correctly?

angularJS code

```
var CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiryController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $window, UsersService) {

$rootScope.title = 'Capital Request Multi Mill Inquiry';
$scope.mill = '';
$scope.jobNumber = '';
$scope.description = '';
$scope.amount = '';
$scope.amountOperator = '';
//below is a textbox entry may need to change
$scope.openonly = '';
$scope.users = '';
$scope.selectedProjectManager = '';


UsersService.getUsersWithId().then(function (objectTypes) {
    $scope.getUsersWithId = _.filter(objectTypes, function (objectTypes)
    {
        return objectTypes.inactive == false;
  });       
});



$scope.search = function() {
    //for each mill

    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://coucmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Inquiry", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.selectedProjectManager, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openonly).then(function (results) {
        $scope.counce = results;
    });
    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://filcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Inquiry", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.selectedProjectManager, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openonly).then(function (results) {
         $scope.filer = results;
     });
    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tomcmmsweb.pca.com/CapitalRequest/Inquiry", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.selectedProjectManager, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openonly).then(function (results) {
        $scope.tomahawk= results;
    });
    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tridentval.pca.com/api/Inquiry/Inquiry/CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiry/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.selectedProjectManager, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openonly).then(function (results) {
        $scope.valdosta = results;
    });
    CapitalRequestService.searchMulti("http://tridentder.pca.com/api/Inquiry/Inquiry/CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiry/Search", authenticatedUser.userName.toUpperCase(), $scope.mill, $scope.jobNumber, $scope.description, $scope.selectedProjectManager, $scope.amount, $scope.amountOperator, $scope.openonly).then(function (results) {
        $scope.deridder = results;
    });
   }
};
```

and this is my service...

```
app.service('UsersService', function ($http, cache) {
return {
    getUsersWithId: function () {
        var objectTypes = cache.get('usersWithId');
        if (!objectTypes) {
            return $http({ method: 'JSONP', url: "/api/core/users/userswithid?callback=JSON_CALLBACK", params: {} }).then(function (result) {
                if (result.data.success) {
                    cache.put('usersWithId', result.data.data);
                    return result.data.data;
                } else {
                    return [];
                }
            });
        } else {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(objectTypes);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
};
});
```

and my controller..

```
Public Class UsersController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

'
' GET: /Users
<PCA.Core.Web.CompressionFilter> _
Function UsersWithId(callback As String) As ActionResult
    Dim res As New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.Response

    Dim catList As New List(Of ViewModels.Core.User)
    For Each u In Trident.Core.Globals.TridentApp.ApplicationCache.Users.AllWithUserID
        catList.Add(New ViewModels.Core.User(u))
    Next
    Try
        res.success = True
        res.message = ""
        res.data = catList.OrderBy(Function(c) c.fullName)
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    Catch ex As Exception
        res.success = False
        res.message = ex.Message
        res.data = ""
        Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
             .Data = res,
             .Callback = callback
            }
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```

and my view

```
          <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        Project Manager:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select style="width: 180px" ng-options="user.value as user.userName for user in allUsers" ng-model="selectedProjectManager">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

the UserController is a different controller than this particular page's controller my boss told me it should not matter the service is calling the right controller i just need to setup my  angular function and call it in the view and it should work he said...they all went on christmas break and im trying to figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set `$scope.allUsers`? I can't see it in your code. Do you use `ui.router`? I'd just like to know where and how you added the controller for the view.

Comment: For starters, I don't see where allUsers is defined.  In order to access it from the view it should be on $scope in CapitalRequestMultiMillInquiryController.